# ControlsFX SpreadSheet error for JDK8 Java FX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm trying to include a `SpreadSheetView` using [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/). However, everytime I try to initialize and instantiate my SpreadSheetview I get following exceptiong message:

> The row 0 has a number of cells different of the column Count declared in the grid.

This is my SpreadSheet generation code:

```
int rowCount = 15;
int columnCount = 10;
ArrayList<ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell>> filas = new ArrayList<>(15);

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell> fila = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    fila = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
        fila.add(SpreadsheetCellType.DOUBLE.createCell(i, j, 1, 1, 0.0));
     }
     filas.add(fila);
 }

GridBase grid = new GridBase();
grid.setRows(filas);
SpreadsheetView costos = new SpreadsheetView(grid);
paneMatriz.getChildren().add(costos);
```

Comment: why don't you ask on ControlsFX mailing list or submit a bug report?

Comment: Are you still experiencing trouble with the SpreadsheetView?

Comment: @Maxoudela I didn't try a recent version ofControlsFX but in that time I couldn't make it work